# What does #define Dbg(fmt,...) (0) mean? warning: expression has no effect

Tags: c++, c, macros, warnings, compiler-warnings

I am working on removing warnings from legacy code when I encountered the below macro

```
#define DISBALE_DEBUG
#ifdef DISBALE_DEBUG
    #define Dbg(fmt,...) (0) 
#else
    #define Dbg print
#endif
```

and used in the below code:

```
#ifdef __arm__
    Dbg("\n %s %s %d  %d \n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, mode);
#endif
```

for which i get the warning: ** expression has no effect**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter the `DISBALE_DEBUG` `#ifdef` branch, the `Dbg` macro will be defined as [a variadic macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) which just consumes its *variadic arguments* and does nothing with them. I.e., a call such as

```
Dbg("\n %s %s %d  %d \n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, mode);
```

will resolve to

```
(0);
```

which, as the compiler accurately warns you about, has no effect.

If you enter the `#else` branch, on the other hand, the `Dbg` macro will just be a replacement, by the pre-processor, with `print`, meaning

```
 Dbg("\n %s %s %d  %d \n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, mode);
```

resolves to

```
print("\n %s %s %d  %d \n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, mode);
```

Now, given the information in your question, it is unclear what `print(...)` will resolve to, as it [is not a standard function in C++ nor C](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/317462/why-isnt-cs-most-basic-printing-function-named-print-instead-of-printf). It's likely another variadic macro or a [variadic function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic).

Comment: Great thanks :) so now this warning has to be suppressed done? cause it is intended like that.

Comment: yes you are correct print(...) is another variadic function.

Comment: @XavierGeoffrey If you may modify this macro, I guess you could try changing it into `#define Dbg(fmt,...) (void)(0)` to possibly avoid the "expression has no effect" warning. Note also, based on the snippet you showed us, we will always enter the `#ifdef` branch and the macro will always expand to nothing. Finally, it may be good to noticed that there's a typo in the pre-processor constant, `DISBALE_DEBUG` should arguably be `DISABLE_DEBUG`, which can lead to confusion in case someone intents to make use of this from the build system.

Comment: @XavierGeoffrey Happy to help! Good luck with your legacy code base, and consider having a look into [GCC's doc page on macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html#Macros) if you run into more macro confusion.